# How to add ToolBar in StaggeredGridView Activity

Tags: android, gridview, toolbar

Im using StaggeredGridView and I want to add ToolBar in StaggeredGridView, this is my Activity:

```
public class CategoryCarActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener, AbsListView.OnItemClickListener {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sgv);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ...
}
```

activity_sgv.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.etsy.android.grid.StaggeredGridView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/grid_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:item_margin="8dp"
app:column_count="@integer/grid_column_count" />

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
app:titleTextColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/text_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

It will not display Toolbar althrough I check Logcat and there are not any errors happened.

How to fix this the problem to Toobar display? Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are unable to see the `ToolBar` as its wrapped beneath the `StaggeredGridView` .

## How to FIX:

Try this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
app:titleTextColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />

<com.etsy.android.grid.StaggeredGridView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/grid_view"
android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:item_margin="8dp"
app:column_count="@integer/grid_column_count" />



<TextView
android:id="@+id/text_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:gravity="center" />
```

Comment: Greate !! It's displayed but back button is not display

Comment: setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

Comment: If it did help, mark it as answer, Where is the back button defined in the XML file?